# Invert colors Java rendering

Tags: java, rendering, slick

I am making a 2d platformer in java using the slick2d engine. I only use 2 colors: black and white. I want to implement a feature were i invert the colors of certain entities. However i can't find a way to do this. Anyone knows of an easy way or function?

Comment: Are the entities loaded from file or drawn by in java? Both cases would support Tinting however I unsure if tinting black with white would work :)

Comment: The graphics are loaded from spritesheets.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on white one first,
add this `Color test = new Color(0f,1f,0f);` then in your render method using your sprite sheet do.

```
spriteSheet.startUse();
test.bind();

//draw sprites

spriteSheet.endUse();
```

If this works then you could simply have a single sprite sheet (of all white) and color it anyway you wish.

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried using the above on one of my enemies' animation:

if(manager.inverted && verticalDir == LEFT){
   Color test = new Color(0f, 1f, 0f);
   moving.getCurrentFrame().startUse();
   test.bind();
   moving.getCurrentFrame().draw(position.x, position.y);
   moving.getCurrentFrame().endUse();
  }

It just stopped my entities from being rendered at all

P.S: I can't get the code tags to work on this site

Comment: @MaltheLange could you post your render code?